# Git workflow: working on two dependant branches

Tags: git, git-workflow

There are 3 branches:

1. `master` = production branch
2. `feature_1` = branch based on `master`
3. `feature_2` = branch dependant on `feature_1`

What is the correct way to merge branch `feature_1` to master when it's finished?
Usually I use rebase, but in this case it will raise lot of conflicts since `feature_2` branch is merging with `feature_1` constantly to be in sync (because it will change all commits hashes in `feature_1` branch).

Using regular merge is the only choice?

Or maybe there is better way for such type of workflow?

---

And another followup question:

1. `master` - contains `feature_1`
2. `feature_1` - finished and merged to master
3. `feature_2` - dependant and synced with `feature_1`
4. `feature_3` - new branch dependant on both `feature_1` and `feature_2` branches

What is the correct way to start working with branch `feature_3`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using merge would be easier in this case instead of rebase, as rebase might raise lot of intermittent conflicts. As far as your follow up question is concerned, keep occasionally merging `master` into `feature1` and `feature2` and keep merging both of them in `feature3`, so that all of them remain in sync, when you eventually merge them into master.

Comment: So you mean if there are any changes to `master` (which is always deployable) - `master` should be merged to every `feature` branch. But if `feature` branch is local only, rebase can be used. Correct?

Comment: I'm saying is use rebase when your branches haven't diverged too much, otherwise use merge irrespective of branch is local or remote. You don't need to merge master after change, just do it occasionally like 5-7 days or so